# Сортировка элементов файла csv

Tags: python, sql, сортировка, csv

Имееются 2 функции , первая вчитывает элементы с файла и создает список этих элементов, вторая выполняет сортировку элементов. Сортировка выполняется на файле с 1000 элементами (числа от 1 до 1000) , с 10.000 также(хотя ждать надо секунд 10), но вот с 50.000 терминал просто ничего не отображает

Подскажите в чем проблема ,  не правильно выбран алгоритм сортировки (для больших файлов) или может какие-то ограничения стоят в пайтоне? Ведь мне нужно будет дальше сортировать миллионы

```
def read_data(amount_data="/Users/valik/Desktop/repos/python-4th-si-week-
sorting-algorithms-Val1706/data_to_sort/" + "fifty_thousand.csv"):
    numbers = []
    with open(amount_data, "r") as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
        for amount in csv_reader:
            for one_amount in amount:
                numbers.append(int(one_amount))
    return numbers


def bubble_sort(numbers=read_data()):
    last_item = len(numbers) - 1
    for i in range(0, last_item):
        for y in range(0, last_item):
            if numbers[y] > numbers[y+1]:
                numbers[y], numbers[y+1] = numbers[y+1], numbers[y]
    return numbers
```

Comment: Используйте встроенную функцию сортировки [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted).

Comment: Конечно бы использовал ее) Но нужно чтобы была  расписанная функция пузырьковой сортироквки

Comment: Измените внутренний цикл сортировки на for y in range(0, last_item - i). Чтобы не проходить ранее отсортированную часть массива.

Comment: попробовал, все-равно 50.000 не тянет ..

Comment: что вам важнее - `сортировать миллионы` или `нужно чтобы была расписанная функция пузырьковой сортироквки` - если вы хотите делать это эфективно и быстро, то это не совсем совместимые понятия...